# Using smarty code inside a smarty assign statement

Tags: php, smarty

I am working with PHP an smarty and I need to put smarty code inside an smarty assign. I make this to a little example:

PHP Part:

```
$smarty->assign('myname', 'Tom'); 
$smarty->assign('mytest', 'Hello {$myname}');
```

Inside the Template:

```
{$mytest}
```

Output:
Hello {$myname}

But I will "Hello Tom" as output.

Does anybody have an idea to solve that problem?

I tried a lot of things, but i will not work.

Comment: I think expressions like `{$variable}` are only parsed if they are in the actual templates, not if they are in assigned values. In the example you've posted, I don't even see the point of it either. If you already know the name at that point, just add it directly when you assign `mytest`. If you have an actual real use-case/problem you're trying to solve, bring that up instead.

Comment: Use double quotes. `$smarty->assign('mytest', "Hello {$myname}");`, then `Hello Tom` will be passed and interpolated from PHP into the template.

Comment: @MarkusZeller - Won't that rather throw an "undefined variable" warning, considering that there is no `$myname`-variable where and when they define the `Hello {$myname}`-string?

Comment: Maybe. `$myname = 'Tom';` must exist of course. Anyhow passing a template into a template won't work. Also the part `Hello {$myname}` should belong inside the template and not passed into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following syntax to put smarty code inside an smarty assign.

```
$smarty->assign('myname', 'Tom'); 
$smarty->assign('mytest', $smarty->fetch('string:Hello {$myname}'));
```